# There is a way to understand when `flutter run` has finished installing the app?

Tags: flutter, command-line-interface

I was wondering if the is a way, officially supported or not to understand when an app is built and installed using `flutter run` it seems like the process stays open waiting for commands.

There is a way of running this in the background and get a signal when is this done and then be able to run another command right after?